# Save to Wantlist vs Save to Favourites

Tags: website-design, terminology

I run a music recommendation site for electronic music vinyl records. 
Users can listen to tracks and save them. The saves are then used as an algorithm to calculate personalized recommendations for the user.

The algorithm works best when the users save all the records they like, so I want to make saves the key action on the site.

I have toyed with multiple versions of the *Save* wording.

- Save to Want list
- save to Favorites
- Add to Want list
- Save

Which would you use? The user can view their 'want list/favorites at anytime.

Comment: Maybe you could have  both. Then the user sees two lists (one of stuff they like that they do not want to buy, and other that they do).
But your algorithm just appends the two lists to generate recommendations.

Comment: Did you use want list instead of wish list for a specific reason? I have not heard of the term want list used much before so I was curious.

Comment: @MichaelLai Wantlist is used on a site called Discogs which is not too dissimilar and I would imagine users of my site would have used Discogs before.

Comment: Mark, Tag, Bookmark, Pin, Track, Follow, Like

Answer (score 6):

Honestly, "Wantlist" sounds a little bit weird as I have never seen it around. "Wishlist" and "Favorites" are more common rather than "Wantlist".

Other than that "Wantlist" or "Wishlist" are more used for the online stores where users can add goods to wishlists and buy those goods later.

I`d stick with "Save to Favorites" or even would implement old good "Like" concept. Users like tracks and those tracks goes to "Likes" list.

Comment: Cool thanks. Wantlist is used on a site called Discogs which is not too dissimilar and I would imagine users of my site would have used Discogs before. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

this is VERY subjective
Some more suggestions
-add to Need list
-save to own list
-add to my precious list

Product teams and marketing people get really go overboard with labeling for these kind of features, but forgetting to check the language their users are speaking. It really depends on your audience, you need to align it in the same language as them.